# Как в Android "нативно" вывести графику, считывать нажатия аппаратных клавиш?

Tags: android, c++, графика

Как в C++ выводить изображение, считывать нажатия аппаратных кнопок, и т д? ОС - Android. Чекал исходный код bootanimation (он же ведь не использует Java, верно?), не совсем понял, в каком направлении мне идти, в какие заголовочные файлы или библиотеки глянуть. Мне нужна "нативная" графика, без мам, пап и Java; только C++.

Comment: А поподробнее, что вы будете делать с этой графикой? Взять что-то типа SDL2 (у которого готовая мини-прослойка на java), и выводить через него OpenGL - не оно?

Comment: честно, я вообще не имею опыта написания графических утилит на C++, мой максимум (и то сами понимаете как) - ncurses/dialog и TKinter. Честно, не хочу использовать Java как-либо, дабы не попадать в зависимость от процесса zygote, который и запускает Java в Android.

Comment: *"не попадать в зависимость от процесса zygote"* Почему?

Comment: хочу независимую от Java графику. Впрочем, примеры через связку с zygote я бы посмотрел, но мой первостепенной интерес - это независимая от Java графика.

Comment: Почему вы этого хотите? Чтобы не учить джаву? Тогда какая разница, есть там этот zygote или нет? Я бы взял SDL2...

Comment: в первую очередь - не учить Java, да. В идеале бы работать с framebuffer напрямую, но это, во1, сложно, во2, может создать проблем. Кастомный bootanimation с этим сделать можно, но никак не приложение, будь то apk или нативный бинарник Unix.

Comment: Короче, берите SDL2.

Comment: Пользовательские приложения на андроид всегда работают поверх java. SDL2 - не исключение.